# Erro ao montar um Json via código

Tags: c#, json

Estou tentando montar um `Json` na seguinte estrutura:

```
"contatos":[{"contato":{"sequencia":"2046","codigo":"2046","nome":"teste balizador","tipo_pessoa":"PJ","cpf_cnpj":"32337775000143","ie":"","im":"","rg":"","tipo_negocio":"","endereco":"Rua Três Pontas","numero":"440","complemento":"","bairro":"Aparecida","cidade":"","cep":"30710-560","uf":"","pais":"","contatos":"Tiny","fone":"(31) 2526-0565","fax":"","celular":"","email":"teste@sgtrack.com.br","id_vendedor":"4","situacao":"A","obs":""}}]
```

porém ao montar o `Json` o meu arquivo fica sem o `contatos`:

```
{"contato":{"sequencia":"2046","codigo":"2046","nome":"teste balizador","tipo_pessoa":"PJ","cpf_cnpj":"32337775000143","ie":"","im":"","rg":"","tipo_negocio":"","endereco":"Rua Três Pontas","numero":"440","complemento":"","bairro":"Aparecida","cidade":"","cep":"30710-560","uf":"","pais":"","contatos":"Tiny","fone":"(31) 2526-0565","fax":"","celular":"","email":"teste@sgtrack.com.br","id_vendedor":"4","situacao":"A","obs":""}}
```

acredito que eu esteja esquecendo de algo  que ainda não percebi.

segue o trecho do meu código:

```
public class contato
        {

            public string sequencia { get; set; }
            public string codigo { get; set; }
             ...
            public string obs { get; set; }

        }

        public class Contatos
        {
            public contato contato { get; set; }
        }

 var contato = new contato
            {
                sequencia = cliente.CodCliente.ToString(),
                codigo = cliente.CodCliente.ToString(),
                ...
                obs = cliente.Observacoes
            };

            var contatosList = new Contatos() { contato = contato };
            var contatos = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(contatosList);
```

Comment: Seu código está faltando padronização de nomenclatura de classes. Normalmente com Maiúscula inicial. você está criando uma variável e instanciando ela mesmo? var contato = new contato

Comment: Qual sentido de criar uma classe Contatos, a partir de contato?

Comment: foi a forma que consegui para chegar ao padrão do Json, estou analisando o codigo e refazendo de forma mais clara e correta.

Comment: O Seu Json tem que ser na primeira estrutura? Alguma regra do front? No caso ele é um Contatos que possui uma lista do objeto de Contato. Certo?

Comment: exatamente, porque pode acontecer que dentro de contatos tenha mais de um contato exemplo:

Comment: "contatos":[{"contato":{"sequencia":"2046","codigo":"2046","nome":"teste balizador","tipo_pessoa":"PJ","cpf_cnpj":"32337775000143","ie":"","im":"","rg":"","tipo_negocio":""},... "contato":{"sequencia": .....}

Comment: Não precisa fazer a roda duas vezes. 
A sua lista vc declara assim
List<Contato> Contatos = new List<Contato>();

Comment: Preenche contato = new Contato {} e depois Contatos.Add(contato);

Answer (score 3):

Tenta algo assim:

Declara a classe Contato. (mantenha padrão das regras de nomenclaturas)

```
public class Contato
{

    public string sequencia { get; set; }
    public string codigo { get; set; }
     ...
    public string obs { get; set; }

}

List<Contato> Contatos = new List<Contato>(); // Na sua função vc declara a lista da classe de Contato. No caso, Contatos.

Contato contatoAux = new Contato { // Preenche a Contato.
     sequencia = cliente.CodCliente.ToString(),
     codigo = cliente.CodCliente.ToString(),
     ...
     obs = cliente.Observacoes
};

Contatos.Add(contatoAux); // adiciona na lista.


// obviamente passou de uma inserção você irá utilizar um foreach. 
contatoAux = new Contato {
     sequencia = cliente2.CodCliente.ToString(),
     codigo = cliente2.CodCliente.ToString(),
     ...
     obs = cliente2.Observacoes
};

Contatos.Add(contatoAux);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Rebecca, entendi perfeitamente, porém depois de serializar não ficou no padrão e o post não foi realizado, como ficou depois: [{"sequencia":"2052","codigo":"2052"......"obs":""}] e o padrão é esse: "contatos"[{ "contato": {"sequencia":"2052","codigo":"2052","...."obs":""}}]

Comment: Como vc fez a serialização?

Comment: bom dia!! desa forma:  var contatos = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Contatos);

Comment: Me passa seu código e como executa, pode ser por aqui https://dotnetfiddle.net/  Cria ele e salva e me envia o link

Comment: Acho que isso aqui vai te ajudar. http://www.macoratti.net/16/07/c_jsonob1.htm

Comment: desculpa a demora. tive outras demandas urgentes aqui. vou criar.

Comment: li o artigo, utilizei o mesmo método e ainda continuo tropeçando na montagem do Json: segue o trecho que realiza o post:

Comment: List<Contato> Contatos = new List<Contato>();

            Contato contato = new Contato
            {
                sequencia = cliente.CodCliente.ToString(),
               
            };
            
            Contatos.Add(contato);

Comment: var contatos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Contatos.ToList(), Formatting.Indented);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(contatos, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = await new HttpClient().PostAsync($"https://api.tiny.com.br/api2/contato.incluir.php/authorize?token={token}&contato={contatos}&formato=json", stringContent);

            string retorno = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: @Gustavo.NET Coloca o código em algum executável como  dotnetfiddle.net  para poder simular, só assim, não consigo ajudar. srsrsr Ou me chama nas redes sociais que vc me passa o código rebecanonato89

Comment: chamei no instagram.

Comment: bom dia segue o link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iZX8Ou